# Creating duplicate records from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
[Froster,Seat1,Seat34,Seat35]
```

*Does anyone know how i can duplicate this list to something like this*

```
[Forster,Seat1],[Froster,Seat34]
```

*and so on?*

*Update!so this is what i have tried so far *

```
ArrayList<String> try1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> try2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        try1.add("Froster");
        try1.add("Seat1");
        try1.add("Seat23");
        try1.add("Seat35");
        System.out.println(try1);

        for (int i = 1; i<=try1.size(); i++){
            try2.add(try1.get(i));

        }
        System.out.println(try2);
```

*So as you can see the seats start from the 1st index position,so now i want to store into another list as follow*

```
{[Forster,Seat1] [Forster,Seat34]}
```

Comment: Post your coding attempt

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava im sorry but im really new to java so i really couldnt implement anything properly

Comment: The site expects you to have made an effort to solve the problem, and mention what doesn't work. Whatever attempt you did make, post it here. It represents your level of understanding too, and whether you stand to benefit from solutions posted here or not (whether you would understand them)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava hey i have updated it, please bear with me

Comment: So in short you need to create a list of lists,try to work out how that is done..also your indices are off by 1, must be from 0 to size() - 1

Comment: You are most welcome @PepoMaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("Froster", "Seat1", "Seat34", "Seat35");
        List<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        String first = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            lists.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(first, list.get(i))));
        }
        System.out.println(lists);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[Froster, Seat1], [Froster, Seat34], [Froster, Seat35]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to use a map for this example:

```
Map<Integer, List> map= new HashMap<Integer, List>();       
map.put(1, Arrays.asList("Forster", "Seat1"));
map.put(2, Arrays.asList("Forster", "Seat1"));
```